# ruby on rails web app controller generates error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am following along a video series, where the author is creating a simple CMS using RoR 4, but I currently have RoR 3.x installed.  I followed all the code to a "T" but when I try to create a simple subject in the simple CMS, I am getting an error.  So I checked the log/production.log

And I am getting the following error,
`TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into String):`

The controller code looks like the following,

```
def create
    # Instantiate a new object using form parameters

    # the below line should work with rails v3.x
    # @subject = Subject.new(params[:subject])

    @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)

    # Save the object
    if @subject.save
      # add flash hash
      flash[:notice] = "Subject created successfully."
      # if save succeeds, redirect to the index action
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      # if save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      render('new')
    end
  end
```

And the private method I created for the subject new params looks like the following

```
 private

    def subject_params
      # same as using "params[:subject]", except that it:
      # - raises an error if :subject is not present
      # - allows listed attributes to be mass-assigned
      params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :position, :visible)
    end
```

Comment: Please give more details about the error. Which file, what lines...etc?

Comment: we definitely need the full error with backtrace.

Comment: I'll ghostbin the `subjects_controller.rb` when I get home.

Comment: you've already posted the controller - we want the error.

Comment: @sevenseacat how would I get the full errror with backtrace?

Comment: @Chris it will be in the server logs, or in your browser (if you click the Full Trace link on the error page)

Comment: There are no strong parameters in RoR3 unless you have them installed as a gem.

Comment: @sevenseacat it's in a production environment, so I don't have web link when it generates an error, I just get a `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author tells you that you need to change `@subject = Subject.new(subject_params)` to `@subject = Subject.new(params[:subject])`.

`params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :position, :visible)` is a Rails 4 feature called [Strong Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).  If you are new to Rails I would suggest you use the version the author uses to alleviate future version issues like this.